# Appositive or other things?

Tags: grammar

> Bidentate (also called didentate) ligands bind with two atoms, an example being ethylenediamine.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denticity

Is "an example being ethylenediamine" a inappropriate appositive?

As far as i know, appositive is usually to define the preceding noun.

> My youngest sister, Meghan, will be visiting soon.

"Meghan" is an appositive describing the preceding noun(sister).

So, is the sentence in the beginning exemplifying a different grammar structure than appositive?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELU! No, this is an [absolute construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).

Comment: Yes, and potentially confusing as well. Much clearer would be a semicolon and a finite clause, instead of the comma and the participle: _.. two atoms; an example is ethylenediamine._

Comment: a lot of thank to StoneyB. It seems like what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, grammatically speaking, the sentence you reference smells as bad as ethylenediamine.  As the sentence is written ethylenediamine is set in apposition to "two atoms."  The sentence from Wikipedia begins to fall apart with the first set of parentheses.  The writer meant to say something like this, "Bidentate, also called didentate, ligands, such as ethylenediamine, bind to two atoms."

Comment: I would definitely not replace the parentheses with commas; I find the sentence almost unreadable that way.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: Shouldn't that be a style rule? *Sentences requiring both weak and strong parenthesization should use both parenthesis and parenthetical commas.*